# How to check if line exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, many-to-many

Is there a way to check if there is already a line with the same entries?

```
             ID            |     Name1               |      Name2           
     ______________________|_________________________|_______________________
              1            |     peter               |      hannah           
  ->          2            |     karl                |      claudia           
              3            |     ted                 |      robin           
              4            |     peter               |      bruce           
              5            |     anna                |      luke
  ->          6            |     karl                |      claudia
```

So that for example, when line two exists, line six can't be written? I think

```
validates uniqueness
```

won't work because it's a many to many relation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead

```
validates_uniqueness_of :Name1, :scope => :Name2
```

Comment: It'd also be nice to add a unique index to the table in a migration: `add_index(:table, [:Name1, :Name2], unique: true)`

Comment: I agree with @ouranos, but anyways validation needs to be added to avoid crashes

Comment: Yes, that's what I said it's nice to have in addition to the validation (should you happen to bypass it somewhere).